# Cannot assign [undefined] to QString error when calling Python code from QML slot

Tags: python, qt, qml, pyside2

I have the following slot defined in my QML:

```
onTextResourceFileToReadChanged: {
        // textArea.text = "Hello world!" // Works, sets text as expected
        textArea.text = TextResourceReader.hello_world() // Doesn't work: "Error: Cannot assign [undefined] to QString"
    }
```

I have the following slot defined in my Python:

```
class Foo(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

@QtCore.Slot()
    def hello_world(self):
        return "Hello world!"
```

My Python class is registered:

`engine.rootContext().setContextProperty("Foo", foo)`

However, when my QML slot `onTextResourceFileToReadChanged` is called I get the following error:

`Error: Cannot assign [undefined] to QString`

Comment: change to `@QtCore.Slot(result=str)`

Comment: Worked like a charm.  I am finding the PySide2 documentation lacking compared to the C++ Qt documentation.  Am I not looking in the right place?

Comment: You want to implement a Q_INVOKABLE in python, and that is to use the argument result as shown in the docs, see https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/extras/PySide.QtCore.Slot.html

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the kind of documentation I was looking for, but was unable to find.